# Layout with image and "bottom bar" issues

Tags: android

I am fairly new at the whole Android thing so I am hoping this is something obvious that I am overlooking since I have not been able to find a solution online yet.

I am creating a view which contains an ImageView and a "bottom bar". The problem I am having is that since the image is larger than the screen and I would prefer to use something similar to "fill_parent" or "wrap_content". Ideally I would set the ImageView's height to "fill_parent-44px", but I have not found a way to do this in the XML.

Eventually I plan to have the ImageView function with multi-touch zoom, so it is therefore not an option to resize the image for different screen resolutions.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy to do this with a `RelativeLayout`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <View android:id="@+id/bottombar"
        android:background="#FFCC00"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true" />

    <ImageView android:id="@+id/image"
        android:src="@drawable/someimage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottombar"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

The important things here are `android:layout_alignParentBottom` and `android:layout_above` (see [RelativeLayout.LayoutParams](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html) for all possible layout attributes).

The `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` is more or less ignored given the right `RelativeLayout` parameters, it just needs to be there to please the Android UI system.

The `android:background` is just for highlighting in the UI designer, and the `bottombar` `View` can be replaced by any other view like, `TextView`, `LinearLayout`, etc.

Comment: Thanks, that is exactly what I was hoping to achieve